# Uniqueness theorem for cycloid in revolution

Tags: calculus, geometry, self-learning

Characterize of the surface of revolution generated by the cycloid in terms of the mean curvature and the Gaussian curvature as a function of the distance $x> 0$ to the axis of revolution.

I did a deep research and only get that there is a line $CD$ and a point $H$ that satisfies the uniqueness of the cycloid and the only curve that satisfies the conditions of the vertical tangent angle proposition, and passes through the point $H$ is the cycloid, but I not get the theorem to prove uniqueness. I need help I've been researching for weeks.

Comment: I have not lot information about this topic, but I don't quite understand your question and I'm not sure if it's your English or my lack of knowledge. If it's your English, it would be good if you can review your question and make it a bit clearer